# QQQ fillings history

Tags: time-series, finance, etf, exchange

I'm trying to find Invesco QQQ Trust fillings for 2001-2018 time period, at least top 10 by year, do you know where I should search?

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: tried google and https://www.morningstar.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the official SEC filings then EDGAR is your best bet. QQQ is still listed under PowerShares, the old (and better IMHO) name for Invesco.

POWERSHARES QQQ TRUST, SERIES 1 CIK#: 0001067839

This link should get you what you need;

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001067839&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100

Based on the comment below I also have a link to the Invesco (horrible name) web site where you can download the daily holding of the QQQ Trust. You need to download the excel sheet to get the shares info. This should be more up to date than anything you could glean from SEC filings.

[Invesco - QQQ Trust](https://www.invesco.com/portal/site/us/financial-professional/etfs/holdings/?javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.pst=72e337bf3b31ef1a015fe531524e2ca0_&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_72e337bf3b31ef1a015fe531524e2ca0_ticker=QQQ)

Just a quick note, filings cover a wide variety of regulatory topics. It seems like what you are looking for is actually a list of Holdings of the trust. That may help you get better answers.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, is it total holdings or shares they are planning to buy?
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067839/000110465915002429/a14-24967_1n30b2.htm

Comment: You can get holdings from the Invesco web site. I highly doubt you will ever find any information about what they are planning to buy.

I edited the answer above to give more specific information.